# Unable to convert rgb to YCbCr and back without loss

Tags: c++, image-processing

I need to write a program that will take pictures, transfer them to YCbCr format, manipulate the picture and then return the result back in RGB format. Before I write the manipulation I wrote the transformation from RGB to YCbCr and back and wanted to test that it works. On most pictures I've tested it on it works, and returns back a picture that is identical to the original. I have problems with 2 pictures, where the transformation seems to change some of the pixels. the pictures are <sup>(cropped areas from larger pictures)</sup>:

The original:

[image]

The result:

[image]

The original:

[image]

The result:

[image]

I'm taking the values for the conversion matrices and vectors from [this site](http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html), and I've tried all the 3 available options, all of them give similar "errors".

The code I use:

```
//transformation matrix from RGB to YCbCr
const double rgb2YCbCrMatrix[3][3] = {
    { 0.257,  0.504,  0.098},
    {-0.148, -0.291,  0.439},
    { 0.439, -0.368, -0.071}
};
//transformation vector from RGB to YcBCr
const char rgb2YCbCrVector[3] = {
    16,
    128,
    128
};
//transformation matrix from YCbCr to RGB
const double TCbCr2rgbMatrix[3][3] = {
    {1.164,  0.000,  1.596},
    {1.164, -0.392, -0.813},
    {1.164,  2.017,  0.000}
};
//transformation vector from RGB to YcBCr
const char YCbCr2rgbVector[3] = {
    -16,
    -128,
    -128};

//calculate the values of the Y, Cb and Cr channels, used the formula for HDTV, as described at http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html
for (int i = 0; i < height*width; i++) {
    YChannel[i]  = redChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[0][0]+greenChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[0][1]+blueChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[0][2] + rgb2YCbCrVector[0];
    CbChannel[i] = redChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[1][0]+greenChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[1][1]+blueChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[1][2] + rgb2YCbCrVector[1];
    CrChannel[i] = redChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[2][0]+greenChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[2][1]+blueChannel[i]*rgb2YCbCrMatrix[2][2] + rgb2YCbCrVector[2];
}
//calculate the values of the RGB channels after the transformation, used the formula for HDTV, as described at http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html
for (int i = 0; i < height*width; i++) {
    redChannel[i]   = (YChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[0])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[0][0]+(CbChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[1])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[0][1]+(CrChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[2])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[0][2];
    greenChannel[i] = (YChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[0])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[1][0]+(CbChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[1])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[1][1]+(CrChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[2])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[1][2];
    blueChannel[i]  = (YChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[0])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[2][0]+(CbChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[1])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[2][1]+(CrChannel[i] + YCbCr2rgbVector[2])*TCbCr2rgbMatrix[2][2];
}
```

Where `redChannel`, `greenChannel` and `blueChannel` as well as `YChannel`, `CbChannel` and `CrChannel` are of `unsigned char *` type, and `height` and `width` are the dimensions of the picture. Why doesn't those pictures return the same, while all other tested pictures return perfectly fine.

**p.s.**

I've tested both pictures in Matlab using the commands `rgb2ycbcr` and `ycbcr2rgb`, and rounding them down with `uint8` and it gave me good results.

```
in=imread(pic);
YCbCr = uint8(rgb2ycbcr(in));
out = uint8(ycbcr2rgb(YCbCr));
imshow(out);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 1-to-1 conversion between YCbCr and RGB. Using the same range of values, there are colors in both color spaces that cannot be represented in the other.

When you do a conversion in either direction, you need to clamp the values to the range.

For example, an RGB to Y conversion needs to have something like this for every component conversion:

```
 double RGBtoY (double R, double G, double B)
{
   . . . . 
   if (result < 0.0)
     result = 0.0 ;
   else if (result > 255) // Or whatever maximum value
     result = 255 ;      
}
```

Otherwise, you are going to get wrap around.

Answer (score 1):

I observed that the glitched areas appear to be in areas that are likely either pure black or white.

Based on this, a guess: rgb2YCbCrVector has type char, for which the value '128' actually overflows to -128.

So in the case of r,g,b=0,0,0 you get Y,Cr,Cb=16,-128,-128 instead of 16,128,128. Then when converting back, the formula gives

```
redChannel = (16-16)*blah + (-128 - 128)*blah2 + (-128 - 128)*blah3
```

Test program:

```
char a = 128;
char b = -128;
printf("%d", a + b);
```

Output:
-256

So when converting back, redChannel = 0*blah1 - 256*blah2 - 256*blah3

Which is clearly not 0 as you would originally expect.

I would consider storing the conversion vectors as float/double, or at least int. Maybe consider doing the same for the color channels too, though not sure that would make a difference.